Optimization under cardinality constraint
When we consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}\label{P}\tag{P}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} & f(x) \\
\text{s.t.} & Ax = b,~ x \geq 0, \\
& \|x\|_0 \leq s.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Here, $\|x\|_0$ denotes the number of nonzero components of a vector $x$, $s \leq n$ is the sparsity parameter, and $f(x)$ is a convex function.
Is there any method to solve this kind of problem in the literature?

You can add a binary variable $y_i$ for each $x_i$, which is activated if $x_i >0$. And add $\sum_i y_i \le s$

The Pseudo ${L}_{0}$ Norm means the problem is an integer problem.
For very small $n$ discrete optimization might work.
For large dimensions you should do something greedy.
Assuming $f$ is smooth, you may use Projected Gradient Descent and using the Hard Threshold Operator as the projection onto the Pseudo ${L}_{0}$ Norm constraint (See Derivation of Hard Thresholding Operator (Least Squares with Pseudo L0 Norm).
You may also utilize ADMM and then break the projection into "smaller pieces".
